# OptionMenu won't show the first option when clicked (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I added a `OptionMenu` widget to my code, and assigned a list as it's options. This is how it is:

```
z = StringVar()   
z.set(userList[0])    
usersOption = OptionMenu(frame1, z, *userList)#, command=changeUser)
usersOption.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=3)
```

Now, I reckon it would show all the options in said list. As so:

```
Option 1 \/ <-- the box with the selected option
Option 1 }\__the options that show on click
Option 2 }/
```

but it actually only shows the second option, and when I choose it there is, basically, no way back, if I click the box again it keeps only showing option 2 and I can't change it even with the up and down keys. I tried looking for solutions, but I got nowhere, so I'm starting to think it is the default operating way of the widget, but I found nothing to show me how to solve it in the documentation I read.
P.S.: I'm using Python 3.3

Comment: is `z` an instance of a Tkinter `StringVar`? Are you absolutely certain that `userlist` has the value you think it has?

Comment: yes, it is and yes, it does. The list is created from a txt file's lines without the line breakers '\n' (for that I use .strip()). This text file has, currently, two lines: "User 1" and "User 2". And it is set to userList[0]. (I'll edit the text to add this)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and it was driving me mad, so i looked in the [source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py?source=cc#L3183). I think the issue is that the 3rd constructor argument is the default value. If you don't specify it before *userList, it looks like it takes the first item as the default value. A real fix would be something like:

```
z = StringVar()   
z.set(userList[0])    
usersOption = OptionMenu(frame1, z, userList[0] ,*userList)#, command=changeUser)
usersOption.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=3)
```

Comment: Yes. As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138534/tkinter-optionmenu-first-option-vanishes)

Comment: Indeed, passing the proper arguments when creating the widget is an excellent suggestion. ;¬)

Answer (score 6):

Late answer..

Just use

```
self.option = OptionMenu(PARENT, VALUE TO BE CHANGED, "DEFAULT TEXT", *OPTIONS_ARRAY/LIST)
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I took the `*userList` off and used a for loop to insert the items as commands. Now it works just fine.
The code I used:

```
for user in userList:
    usersOption["menu"].insert("end", "command", label=user, command=_setit(z, user, changeUser))
```

Comment: IMO, this is a very hacky way of doing things because it's making use of the private `_setit()` function defined in the module. Since you obviously peeked at the source code, why not just pass the proper arguments to the widget's constructor instead?